# Converting PBF vector tiles to GeoJSON?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, google-maps-api, pbf

I am working on Google Maps with AirMap API. AirMap API provides me with vector tile data in `pbf`-format.

I want to render it into Google Maps. I have researched that to render `pbf` vector tiles on Google Map, I need to convert it into GeoJSON data. I have a lot researched about it but I haven't found any tool to convert PBF to GeoJson or tutorial. Any suggestions about how to?

Comment: OSM PBF can be converted to OSM XML. There should be multiple OSM XML to GeoJSON converters available.

Comment: @scai, Thank you for your reply. I have tried many tools like OSMCONVERT, OGR2OGR and OSMOSIS. But my bad luck, it shows me "Invalid file format".

Comment: You can also try [osmium](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/). If all tools fail then this is probably not an OSM PBF file. I guess it is a MapBox-specific format. Not sure how to handle this.

Comment: @scai, Yes you are right. It could be mapbox specific format.

Answer (score 10):

Your data seems to be [Mapbox Vector Tiles](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/) in pbf format.

GDAL 2.3 can process this data: https://www.gdal.org/drv_mvt.html

Note that [MB tiles](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec) and [OSM pbf](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) files are something completely different.

Comment: +1 for clarifying the difference between different pbf! I got confused for a long time. The link you provided is also very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use tippacanoe-decode to convert PBF files to GeoJSON.

https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#tippecanoe-decode

Answer (score 3):

No, You can not.

Why? click here for details

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/940/pbf-not-work-with-mapserver-but-work-with-featureserver

Mapbox vector tile is different from PBF, even MBTile use PBF format.

Let me explain, PBF is a compressed format for json. You can zip json, you can PBF json, the difference is zipped json larger in size, you can get only the data you need from a pbf json, without parse whole dataset.

mapbox vector tile,  '.mbtile' is a set of data, not a single piece of data

you are trying to convert a bunch of dataset into a single piece of geojson, it is not possible( possible by previous answers above), even possible, but does not make sense.  You try to convert a few piece of tile into a geojson? does not make any sense, since a few tile maybe contain a cutted partial of a polygon, line, these cutted partial polygon or line can't be a geojson.

The only case it possible is if you try to convert a single piece pbf to a single piece of geojson.

For example, arcgis REST api, you can use http URL like

```
          '...?f=pbf'
```

instead of

```
          '...?f=json',
```

you will get a single piece of response from .xhr,

you can use [mapbox pbf](https://github.com/mapbox/pbf) to unzip pbf back to json.

Here is a tool to convert ESRI pbf format into json

https://github.com/rowanwins/arcgis-pbf-parser

Here is ESRI pbf format

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pbf/tree/main/proto/FeatureCollection

Here is a library for retrieving features from an ArcGIS FeatureServer or MapServer. This library makes tiled requests rather than simply requesting every feature.

https://github.com/rowanwins/mapbox-gl-arcgis-featureserver

Answer (score 1):

You can use QGIS to load your .pbf file and once you drag and drop the file on QGIS the data will be displayed as a layer on map, then:

Right click on the layer > Save as >  Change format `Format: GeoJSON`, choose the layer name and set `COORDINATE_PRECISION=5` (recommended).

And done! Your pbf file is converted to GeoJSON.

Or you can use [`ogr2ogr`](https://www.compose.com/articles/how-to-transform-and-use-openstreetmap-data-into-geojson-using-gdal/), which is a commandline tool for converting osm to GeoJson.

Comment: The requested pbf vector tiles format has nothing to do with the osm pbf format.

Comment: QGIS can add Mapbox pbf tiles as well, as of version - https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector_tiles/vector_tiles_properties.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a JavaScript library to load vector tiles (pbf) in Google Maps.
https://github.com/techjb/Vector-Tiles-Google-Maps

Hope it will help you.